# incrementing a global variable within a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, scope

I know it sounds like a duplicate question- I know because I've clicked on like 10 SO posts labeled the same thing, but hear me out.

I have a function like below

```
class Solution:
    def confusingNumberII(self, N: int) -> int:
        valid = {0: 0, 1: 1, 6: 9, 8: 8, 9: 6}
        count = [0]
        def dfs(n, rotate, digit):
            if n != rotate:
                count[0]+=1
            for num in valid:
                cur = n * 10 + num
                if cur > N: return
                dfs(cur, valid[num] * digit + rotate, digit * 10)
                
        for num in valid:
            if num != 0:
                dfs(num, valid[num], 10)
        return count[0]
```

And I feel like setting a len-1-list to keep track of count which will be incremented in `dfs` is bad practice.

What I've tried:

- I've read like 10 different stackoverflow posts that say "just declare `global` variableName in the function that will update it" but it seems to be a past-time solution. I get an error that says `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'int'`
  [image]
- I've also read a post that says I should increment count = 0 not by `count +=1` but by `count = count + 1`. This doesn't work either and throws the same error.
- I've also tried passing count in as a variable to update it- it doesn't do anything and the entire function ends up returning 0.

Is there a clean way of updating a single `int` variable? I really feel like it shouldn't be this clunky to update a variable.

Comment: add leetcode problem link for people to understand what are you doing? plus use `nonlocal` instead of global

Comment: btw you can use combination of `[0,1,6,8,9]` to get all the possible combinations and then from those combination filter the result based on whether there 180 degree rotation would be reruslt into a different no or not

Comment: Just in case you missed it, the issue is that `count` is not a global.  You need `nonlocal` to refer to an outer variable that is not a global.

Comment: @TimRoberts Aha. Yes, swapping out the `global` for `nonlocal` worked as an accepted solution. I was asking the wrong question *facepalm* . Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the global variable by letting `dfs` calculate the count for its own given input only, and *return* that. The caller is then responsible of accumulating the counts that are returned from the recursive calls:

```
class Solution:
    def confusingNumberII(self, N: int) -> int:
        valid = {0: 0, 1: 1, 6: 9, 8: 8, 9: 6}

        def dfs(n, rotate, digit):
            count = int(n != rotate)
            for num in valid:
                cur = n * 10 + num
                if cur > N:
                    break
                count += dfs(cur, valid[num] * digit + rotate, digit * 10)
            return count

        count = 0
        for num in valid:
            if num != 0:
                count += dfs(num, valid[num], 10)
        return count
```

For what it's worth, you can rewrite the above code in a more *function programming* style, like this:

```
from itertools import takewhile

class Solution:
    def confusingNumberII(self, N: int) -> int:
        valid = {0: 0, 1: 1, 6: 9, 8: 8, 9: 6}

        def dfs(n, rotate, digit):
            return int(n != rotate) + sum(
                dfs(n * 10 + num, valid[num] * digit + rotate, digit * 10)
                    for num in takewhile(lambda num: n * 10 + num <= N, valid)
            )

        return sum(
            dfs(num, valid[num], 10)
                for num in valid
                    if num != 0
        )
```